# Disambiguate functional interface in lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

Suppose this:

```
ExecutorService service = ...;

// somewhere in the code the executorService is used this way:
service.submit(() -> { ... });
```

The lambda expression would default to `Callable`.

Is there a way to make it instantiate a `Runnable` instead?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could define it above as an instance of runnable

Comment: Sure, but how to do it with lambdas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare it as a Runnable, or use a cast:

```
Runnable r = () -> { ... };
executorService.submit(r);
```

or

```
executorService.submit((Runnable) () -> { ... });
```

Comment: More generally, this answer comes down to: provide a _target type_ for the lambda.  Assignment, cast, and method invocation contexts are some of the ways to provide a target type.

Answer (score 3):

Your premise is wrong. This invocation does not default to `Callable`. The selection is made via the shape of the lambda expression, i.e. whether it returns a value:

```
ExecutorService service = null;

// somewhere in the code the executorService is used this way:

// invokes submit(Runnable)
service.submit(() -> {  });
// invokes submit(Runnable)
service.submit(() -> { return; });
// invokes submit(Callable)
service.submit(() -> "foo");
// invokes submit(Callable)
service.submit(() -> { return "foo"; });

// in case you really need disambiguation: invokes submit(Runnable,null)
service.submit(() -> { throw new RuntimeException(); }, null);
// dito (ignoring the returned value)
service.submit(this::toString, null);
```

Note that if you don't need the returned `Future`, you can simply use `execute(Runnable)` to directly enqueue a `Runnable`, rather than having it wrapped in a `FutureTask`.

Answer (score 2):

```
   service.submit((Runnable) () -> {
      ...
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `Callable` and `Runnable` in terms of their signature is that `Callable` is returning a value, while `Runnable` doesn't.

So `() -> { }` is a `Runnable` while e.g. `() -> ""` is a `Callable`.